# Does lifelink still trigger if I concede before damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In a multiplayer game one of my opponents has a [felidar sovereign](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bfelidar%20sovereign%5d) and is at 39 life and I am at 2 life. He attacks me with a 2/2 lifelink creature, but before damage is dealt I concede. Does the lifelink still gain my opponent enough life to win with felidar sovereign at the beginning of his upkeep, thereby letting my other opponent lose the game or do I only lose and do my opponents still need to continue the game to determine who wins?

Comment: Related also: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32736/in-multiplayer-can-a-player-concede-abusively/32737

Comment: Of course, you could have used lighting bolt on him and rob him of 3 life instead of just 2.

Comment: @GendoIkari Or the creature so you don't die and they don't win (yet)

Comment: @diego  I should have chosen something that could only deal damage to myself

Comment: @IvardeBruin Lava Spike can only target players if you want to change it

Comment: @diego it is a sort of duplicate so no need to change it anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifelinking creature does not deal damage, which means your opponent does not gain life, and the rest of the table will need to keep playing.