# What would happen to other players creatures upon death?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Kalitas, Traitor of Ghet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKalitas%2c%20Traitor%20of%20Ghet%5d) in play. We are playing with 3 people. If i beat one player, would the creatures he own die? So i would get 2/2 zombie tokens from his creatures?

Comment: I couldnt find theanswer in that post, probally im not reading it right. English isnt my mother language.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Comprehensive Rules (http://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/MagicCompRules_20170119.txt), this is what happens when a player loses the game:

> 104.5. If a player loses the game, he or she leaves the game. [...]
>
> 800.4a When a player leaves the game, all objects (see rule 109) owned by that player **leave the game** and any effects which give that player control of any objects or players end. [...]

The definition of the word "die" is:

> A creature “dies” if it is **put into a graveyard** from the battlefield.

Since a losing player's creatures leave the game instead of being put into a graveyard, those creatures are not considered to have died, and Kalitas does not give you any tokens.

Comment: Must the losing player always prevent as much damage as possible or can he just take al the damage to avoid any combat? To prevent me to get any tokens at all? Because it can influence the game in multiplayer.

Comment: @Hans There's no rule saying that players have to try to avoid taking damage.

Comment: A player does not have to prevent any damage, except if cards say they have to. No matter if the damage would be lethal or not.

Comment: @Hans I think what you're realising here is that it is possible to be abusive in multiplayer MtG, for example by making decisions which favour one of your opponents over another. The "kingmaker problem" is present in a lot of board/card games unfortunately.

Comment: You can read more about that particular thing here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32736/in-multiplayer-can-a-player-concede-abusively/32737

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed the kingmaker problem was occured yesterday, but that player was kind to give us both something in return